# Determinan Matrix NxN with function recursion from text .csv

Tags: c, recursion, matrix, determinants

i want to calculate the determinant of the NxN matrix by using a recursive function from CSV file. I'm comparing the result of my CSV file with the matrix values which I store directly in `int`.

In my CSV file (which has the same value as the value in int) the determinant is 0, it should be -7.
I'm confused where my error lies because both have the same value but the results are different, I tried looking for it but haven't found it. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int dete(int, int (*)[]);

char buffer [200];
char *record, *line;
int p,q; // original matrix dimensions
int mat[100][100];
int rows,columns;

int main()
{
   FILE *fp = fopen("", "r"); 
    if (fp==NULL) 
    {
        printf("the file cannot be opened!");
    }

rows=0;
while ((line=fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) != NULL)
{
    columns=0;
    record = strtok(line, ";");  
    while (record!=NULL)
    {
        mat[rows][columns] = atoi(record);
        record = strtok(NULL, ";"); 
        columns++; 
    } 
    rows++; 
}

p=columns-1;
q=rows;

printf("Matriks from File CSV: \n");
for ( rows = 0; rows < q; rows++)
{
    for ( columns = 0; columns < p+1; columns++)
    {
        printf("%3d\t", mat[rows][columns]); 
    }
    printf("\n");
}


   int a[3][3]=
   {
        1,4,5,
        7,9,10,
        1,6,8,
   };
printf("\n a : %d\n", a[1][1]);
printf("\n mat : %d\n", mat[1][1]);


int ans1,ans2;
ans1=dete(3,a);//ans1 = 46 and this is correct
ans2=dete(3,mat);//ans2 = 46 but it is giving 0 which is wrong
printf("determinan form int a[3][3] : %d\n", ans1);
printf("determinan form file csv: %d", ans2);
getch();
}
int dete(int row, int arr[][row])
{
     int col_main_mark,col_main,row_main,col_minor,cof,x,y;
     int minor[row-1][row-1];
     int det=0;

 if(row==2)//condition to stop recursion
 {
      det = arr[0][0] * arr[1][1] - arr[0][1] * arr[1][0];
      return det;
 }

 for(col_main_mark=0; col_main_mark<row; col_main_mark++)//for specific col value of main matrix (arr[row][row])
 {
      cof=arr[0][col_main_mark];

      //following two loop will make the minor matrix (minor[row-1][row-1]) from the main marix
      for(row_main=0; row_main<row; row_main++)
      {
           for(col_main=0,col_minor=0; col_main<row; col_main++)
           {
                if(col_main==col_main_mark)
                continue;

                minor[row_main][col_minor]=arr[row_main+1][col_main]; col_minor++;
           }
      }

      det = det + cof * pow(-1,col_main_mark) * dete(row-1, minor);  
 }
 return det;
```

}

and there is my result in terminal:

```
  1       4       5
  7       9      10
  1       6       8

 a : 9
 mat : 9
determinan form int a[3][3] : -7
determinan form file csv: 0
```

the determinant in both should be the same. Please help me.

Comment: The dimension of `mat` is 100x100

Comment: thankyou it works, but if i give mat[3][3], my matrix is no longer recursive, is it? i try to give mat[rows][columns] but its not work to:(